# PHPでファイルのダウンロード機能を作りたい

Tags: php, cakephp

タイトルの通りなのですが、ファイルのアップロード機能は作れたのですが、ダウンロード機能が作れません。
どなたか経験あるかたご教授願いたいです。(フレームワークはcakePHPを使用しています）

Comment: 質問の投稿ありがとうございます。もう少し詳しい要件を共有してもらえますか? (質問は後から[edit]できます。) 今の質問文ですと「ダウンロード機能というのはこういうことかな」という推測を含んだ回答が多くなってしまいそうです。既についている回答のように「特定のファイルをダウンロードさせるようなレスポンスの返し方」ということで大丈夫でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

cakephpというよりはノーマルのphpの問題かと思います。
下記のようなphpを作って、htmlからリンクを張りましょう。

```
<?php
$file = "test.txt";
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

cakeらしいやり方としては以下の２点があります。
この方法ですと自分でレスポンスヘッダーを記述しなくていいので
楽かも。

http://qiita.com/madiehak/items/9b104be97c4c37a3465d
http://www.php-kaihatsu.com/blog/649.html